# Using results of an aggregation to filter documents in another index

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I have 2 indexes:

- `users`
- `navigations`

Let's say `users` looks like this:

```
{
  "properties": {
    "cookies": {"type": "keyword"},
    "name": {"type": "text"}
  }
}
```

And `navigations` looks like this:

```
{
  "properties": {
    "url": {"type": "keyword"},
    "cookie_id": {"type": "keyword"}
  }
}
```

As you can notice, `users` and `navigations` can be joined together by the `cookie_id` and `cookies` fields.

Actually my indexes have more fields but only these are necessary to demonstrate my issue.

I'm storing `users` and `navigations` in 2 different indexes instead of using a `join` mapping or a `nested` mapping because I'll have a lot more `navigations` than users and in the majority of my search use cases I'll only search for `users`, thus I don't want to maintain a list of `navigations` per `users`. I prefer keeping them separate (I also have some other constraints that drive my choice for 2 separate indexes such as data reconciliation, etc...).

What I'd like to do is a query/aggregation like this: *"give me all users with `name` `Fabien` that navigated 5 times on `url` `http://example.com`"*

I had the following query/aggregation so far (the search query is done on my 2 indexes):

POST /users,navigations/_search

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {"match": {"name": "Fabien"}}
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "all_navs": {
        "global": {},
        "aggregations": {
            "cookies": {
                "terms": {"field": "cookie_id"},
                "aggregations": {
                    "page_visited": {
                        "filter": {
                            "bool": {
                                "must": [
                                    {"term": {"url": "http://example.com"} }
                                ]
                            }                           
                        },
                        "aggregations": {
                            "number_page_visited": {
                                "value_count": {"field": "type"}
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "count_filter": {
                        "bucket_selector": {
                            "buckets_path": {
                                "count": "page_visited>number_page_visited"
                            },
                            "script": "params.count > 5"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

With this query I can filter my `users` with `name = Fabien`, and I can get the `cookie_id` value from `navigations` where there are at least 5 documents with `url = http://example.com`.

But I can't figure out how to use the `cookie_id`s from my aggregation to filter my `users`.

Any idea?

Thank you!

Comment: Are u sure its worth to use aggregation when it's adding so much complexity to your query, u are making get query much more complex by saving some complexity in indexing, which seems opposite to what we generally do

Comment: i understand that navigation will have much more inserts, so maybe u can change your db design a little bit, make navigation as parent and add user inside navigation as nested field

Comment: parent/children join mapping wouldn't be a better solution? (by having all my data in the same index)

Comment: you should create a separate index for it which contains both fields, as far as i understand, each index in elastic is dedicated for a special type of search queries, in your case searching for url

Comment: yes, join mapping is probably the solution to your problem. From the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/parent-join.html#_parent_join_and_performance) : The only case where the join field makes sense is if your data contains a one-to-many relationship where one entity significantly outnumbers the other entity. It seems to be your use case.

Comment: Moreover, joining data from multiple indices is not possible with Elasticsearch. You can either use join mapping, denormalization or perform join externaly (but it comes with a huge performance cost). The recommended way is denormalization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution with two separate indices

Because elasticsearch is not a relational database, you will not be able to retrieve your results in a single request. It is a strong limitation of elasticsearch, but it is also a major reason for its great performances.

Basically, elasticsearch will compile your query into a Lucene query and perform a scan of the indices using the Lucene query. There is no mechanism where some parameter in the query (e.g. the value of the `user_id` field) is dependent of the result of another query (e.g., find all `id` values from `users` where the name is "Fabien").

You will have to perform the join externally :

- first, retrieve all documents from index `users` where name is `Fabien`. If the number of documents is not bounded, you will have to perform a [scroll search](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.5/search-request-body.html#request-body-search-scroll) or use [search_after](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.5/search-request-body.html#request-body-search-search-after)
- second, retrieve all documents from index `navigation` where `user_id` is in the set of documents returned from the first request and where your other criterion are satisfied.

This approach can be slow and you do not have guarantees that the users index has not been updated when you run the second query.

### Solution with join mapping

Actually if you use [join type mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/parent-join.html), you do not need to use aggregations for your use case.

Please note that join field has [several restriction](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/parent-join.html#_parent_join_restrictions) and is not recommended as the default solution to model one to many relationships.

Here is a working example to should work for your requirement.

The mapping : contains both user and navigation field plus a join field.

```
PUT /user_navigation
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "cookies": {
                "type": "keyword"
            },
            "name": {
                "type": "keyword"
            },
            "join_field": {
                "type": "join",
                "relations": {
                    "user": "navigation"
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Add some testing documents. Two parent documents have `name: Fabien` but only one have two children with `cookies: http://example.com`. The other document has two children with `cookies: http://example.com` but is not named with `Fabien`.

```
POST user_navigation/_doc/_bulk
{ "index" : { "_index" : "user_navigation", "_id" : "1" } }
{ "name" : "Fabien", "join_field": "user" }
{ "index" : { "_index" : "user_navigation", "_id" : "2" } }
{ "name" : "Fabien", "join_field": "user" }
{ "index" : { "_index" : "user_navigation", "_id" : "3" } }
{ "name" : "Autre", "join_field": "user" }
{ "index" : { "_index" : "user_navigation", "routing": "1" } }
{ "cookies": "http://example.com", "join_field": { "name": "navigation",  "parent": "1"  }}
{ "index" : { "_index" : "user_navigation", "routing": "1"} }
{ "cookies": "http://example.com", "join_field": { "name": "navigation",  "parent": "1"  }}
{ "index" : { "_index" : "user_navigation", "routing": "2"} }
{ "cookies": "http://example.com", "join_field": { "name": "navigation",  "parent": "2"  }}
{ "index" : { "_index" : "user_navigation", "routing": "2"} }
{ "cookies": "other_url", "join_field": { "name": "navigation",  "parent": "3"  }}
{ "index" : { "_index" : "user_navigation", "routing": "3"} }
{ "cookies": "http://example.com", "join_field": { "name": "navigation",  "parent": "3"  }}
{ "index" : { "_index" : "user_navigation", "routing": "3"} }
{ "cookies": "http://example.com", "join_field": { "name": "navigation",  "parent": "3"  }}
```

The following request use [has_child query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-has-child-query.html) and will return only the document with `name: Fabien` and such that it has at least two children document with `cookies: http://example.com`.

```
GET user_navigation/_doc/_search
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "term": {
                        "name": "Fabien"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "has_child": {
                        "type": "navigation",
                        "query": {
                            "term": {
                                "cookies": "http://example.com"
                            }
                        },
                        "min_children": 2,
                        "inner_hits": {}
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

The response will contain only the document with id 1.

`"min_children"` parameter allows to change the minimum number of children documents that must fulfill the request.

`"inner_hits": {}` allows to retrieve the children documents in the response.

Comment: Thank you. This is what I'm looking for. However, I saw in the limitations of join mapping that a child MUST have a parent. But in my case, I can have navigations without any parent (because when I receive the navigation I have cases where I don't know the parent id at the beginning). In that case how should I proceed? Should I use another index to store navs without parent and then move them in the other index as soons as I know there parent?

Comment: Yes you could do that but it might complicated to maintain. Another solution (if it fits your use case) would be to assign them to a fake parent. One drawback is that if you have many navigation document with this parent, they would all be assigned to the same shard.

Comment: I don't think keeping them in another index would be more difficult to maintain that assigning them a fake parent. In both cases I have to be able to retrieve them and to update them. Having them in another index is something that could be good in my case because I'll never need to do searches on them, only those with a parent are useful for search in my case